# using command variable in column output not working

Tags: arrays, bash, formatting

I'm using a script that uses curl to obtain specific array values from a configuration.  I'd like to place the output into columns separating values (values are unknown to script).  Here's my code:

```
# get overlay networks and their details
get_overlay=`curl -H "X-Person-Token: $auth_token" -H "X-Person-Email: $auth_email" -k "$api_host/api/v1/networks"`

# array of overlay names with uuid
overlay_name=`echo $get_overlay | jq '.[] | .name'`
overlay_uuid=`echo $get_overlay | jq '.[] | .uuid'`
    echo ""
    echo -e "Overlay UUID\n$oname $ouuid" | column -t
exit 0
```

Here's the ouput:

```
Overlay                                 UUID
"TESTOVERLAY"
"Auto_API_Overlay"
"ANOTHEROVERLAYTEST"                    "ea178905-6ab0-4154-ab05-412dc4b39151"
"e5be9dbe-b0fc-4e30-aaf5-ac4bdcd863a7"
"850ebf6b-3651-4cf1-aae1-5a6c03fad61b"
```

What I was expecting was:

```
Overlay                                 UUID
"TESTOVERLAY"                           "ea178905-6ab0-4154-ab05-412dc4b39151"
"Auto_API_Overlay"                      "e5be9dbe-b0fc-4e30-aaf5-ac4bdcd863a7"
"ANOTHEROVERLAYTEST"                    "850ebf6b-3651-4cf1-aae1-5a6c03fad61b"
```

I'm an absolute beginner at this, any insight is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `paste` to combine your two variables line by line:

```
paste <(printf 'Overlay\n%s\n' "$name") <(printf 'UUID\n%s\n' "$uuid") | column -t
```

Two process substitutions are used to pass the contents of each variable along with their titles.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Fenech!  Your suggestion worked like a charm.  I had realized after I posted that the commands I am using were not single line entries.